# List of common Date (and Time) formats by country/culture

Tags: .net, date, date-format, culture, country

Is there some kind of list of all common Date (and Time) formats?
One of our customers had a problem inputting a date, because he was using something like this:
`2003. 11. 9`.

I already found this very good wiki page:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country

I am only looking for european countries and relevant formats. Another possibility would be to use C# and change the CultureInfo to print out the short date pattern I guess.

Maybe someone has better ideas or can help me find other solutions.

Comment: How do you want it? Want it programmatically? Or a list somewhere for reference?

Answer (score 2):

You can get it programmatically like this:

```
//by culture
var formats = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns());

//or by country (only specific cultures has region/country info)
var formats = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
    .GroupBy(x => new RegionInfo(x.Name).DisplayName)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.SelectMany(y => y.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns()).Distinct().ToArray());
```

For reference, [this](http://techmantium.com/culture-codes/) is the most comprehensive I've found

Comment: I just tried to check out your reference link and found it dead. Do you have any other similar references?

Comment: Code doesnt prove anything, only how Microsoft and/or you have decided to set up CultureInfo objects on the machine you run this code on

Comment: @AndrewBullock How can *I* set up culture info objects on my machine, given the above code? I am not using just any one of the machine specific regions or  cultures, but iterating through every culture MS has to offer. How is that me setting it up?